# dense graph and zero-dimensional set in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let $h\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function with dense graph and $g\colon (2,3)  \to \Bbb R$ be a homeomorphism. Put, $f:=h\circ g\colon (2,3)\to \Bbb R$ still have a dense graph in $(2,3)\times \Bbb R$. Consider a set  $D\subset (-1,1)\times\Bbb R$ that is closed zero-dimensional set such that $$D\cap  Gr(h)=\emptyset $$ where $Gr(h)$ is the graph of the function $h.$ Now, $$D\subset (-1,1)\times\Bbb R\cong (2,3)\times\Bbb R$$ That means there is a homeomorphism $$H\colon (-1,1)\times\Bbb R\to (2,3)\times\Bbb R$$ Now, $H[D]$ is still closed and I think still zero-dimensional. My question : Can we ensure that $$H[D]\cap Gr(f)=\emptyset ?$$

Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: @RobArthan, $h\circ g$ is  not a homeomorphism

Comment: @RobArthan, I fixed it was a typo

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense now.

Comment: @RobArthan, forgot to ask you . By saying makes sense.  Do you mean the answer true? Or you meant just the question is make sense.

Comment: I just meant that the question now makes sense - although you could usefully clarify what definition of dimension you are using.

Comment: @RobArthan, I see, sorry, I missed your question . what did you mean?

Comment: You talk about $D$ being "zero-dimensional": what notion of dimension are you using?

Comment: @RobArthan, A space is zero-dimensional iff each point of $X$ has consisting nbood consisting of open and closed set. like Cantor set is zero dimensional. But this is not important. I want to ensure my question.

Comment: @RobArthan, The idea , I just made a copy of the function $h$ in the interval (2,3) and I need to make sure the homeomorphic image of $D$ still disjoint with $Gr(f)$